# Gallery onClick

Tags: android, onclick, gallery

I have a gallery that's loaded via a `BaseAdapter`. This works fine. I was interested in keeping track of which item in the gallery is clicked.  When I add an `AdapterOnClickListener`, this seems to override the actual gallery click.  Meaning, it will break in the click event, but the gallery has lost it's normal functionality (i.e. it doesn't set focus to the item clicked).

Is there a way to keep track of which item in a gallery is clicked?

Comment: yes you have to implement onclick seperately on each item in the adapter itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set on ItemClickListener in gallery object

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Log.d("LOG","Item selected at position "+position +" in "+currentPosition); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **setTag()** when you construct view from adapter. Then use **getTag()** to find which view is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this might come in handy elsewhere.